# TwiML Sip only dialing the first one

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I am trying to get all of our customer care team's phone's to ring on inbound call's using twiml, but it only ever ring's the first one, Both test phone's are registered through twilio's Sip Domain, and depending on which one is first, that is the one that rings, Here is an exmple of my twiml ( Generated through there function's )

```
<Response>
<Dial>
<Sip>sip:test1@testdomianasdf.sip.us1.twilio.com</Sip>
<Sip>sip:test2@testdomianasdf.sip.us1.twilio.com</Sip>
</Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: I also have tried it without the sip:

Answer (score 0):

Per Twilio's Support,  are not able to do "simulring", and also can not do "simulring" on  if the number is hosted through twilio due to some timing issue :(

Answer (score 0):

SimRing is not support on SIP End-points. It is supported using Number and Client nouns.

If you register SIP clients under the same SIP URI, up to 10 will ring.

Comment: Unfortunately for my use case that will not work, I need all inbound call's to be able to ring all of our customer service team's phone's, but also need the ability to ring each phone individually

Comment: And I found it is also not supported by Number if it is a Twilio number

Answer (score 0):

Twilio now allows "parallel" calls via SIP:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/sip?code-sample=code-parallel-calling-11

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Sip>sip:alice-soft-phone@example.com</Sip>
    <Sip>sip:alice-desk-phone@example.com</Sip>
    <Sip>sip:alice-mobile-client@example.com</Sip>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```